# All of my Wordpress AJAX requests returns html page for subscribers. Why?

Tags: database, wordpress, permissions, custom-post-type

I have my ajax post calls from to create post by users under a custom post. I have used the action hook in all works fine for admins. But when a subscriber uses the same, it returns a html but not the response.

But the server-side is working fine on the ajax call. Meaning, the post has been created successfully and the mail also has been sent as expected (as per the code).

I have defined the ajax action hook for both prev and nonprev users.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_register_participant', 'register_participant_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_register_participant', 'register_participant_callback');
```

I have also defined the capability type and map_meta_cap while registering the custom post type and set the permission to edit, update and delete the 'registration' post type.

```
'capability_type'=> 'registration',
'map_meta_cap' => true,
```

It was actually working fine but suddenly stopped working on all my ajax calls.

Any suggestions to debug?

Comment: I'd start by enabling WP debugging (logging to wp-content/debug.log file) and add error_log('...') test messages to the start and end of `register_participant_callback`, then tail the log and see if this actually fires, and/or produces an error somewhere inbetween. Also, it might be interesting to know what HTML output it produces (maybe a WP error, saying the site encountered an internal error).

Comment: Thanks for the suggession..I have done the same and removed some of the errors on the functions also (some index errors was there). Now there is no error logged out in the `debug.log` when I fire the function `register_participant_callback`. But still the issue persists.

Comment: This error is only when the subsriber do the ajax call. But when I logged in as admin, this error does not appear and everything works fine.